# passing in form variables to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey guys just trying to pass some stuff into my controller. Using codeigniter the below form isn't actually redirecting me anywhere, what's wrong?

my second question is how to do i grab the data in my controller just a simple..?

```
$data = $this->input->$post('search');
```

---

```
<?php
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');

?>
 <form  action="<?php echo site_url('home/id_search');?>" method="post"><input type="submit" value="submit" id="" name="" >
</form>
```

Comment: move `<form  action="<?php echo site_url('home/id_search');?>" method="post">` to the top, above first `<?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you placed the form opening tag in wrong position, do:

```
 <form  action="<?php echo site_url('home/id_search');?>" method="post">
<?php
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');

?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="" name="btnSubmit" />
</form>

And to get POST date in you controller, do:
$data = $this->input->post('shirts'); //for getting shirts form field value
```

Comment: @coosal you have to wait 10  min ~_~